# MDT WSUS update fails

Tags: windows, update, wsus, mdt

We are currently determining if MDT is applicable within our organization. 
We have created a testlab were we test different settings and steps but are unable to deploy updates after an image with our WSUS server. we have tried the following setting:

-editting customsetting.ini `(WSUSServer=http://WSUSServer:8530)`

-editting WSUS server to update to unkown stations

-enable windows update in the task sequance

-installing a WUA Agent on the client

Do you guys have any other suggestions?

Comment: Are you able to ping the wsus server? What is the image you are deploying, is it the standard windows install image? Have you hash checked it prior to import? What version of MDT are you using?

Comment: Hi ,                                                                                                                       Yes we are able to ping the wsus server and we are currently trying to deploy Windows 10 Enterprise. MDT version is MDT 2013 Update 1 preview. Can you please explain what you mean by hash check prior import? or do you mean hash check the .iso file?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I meant hash check the iso file before importing it to MDT.

Comment: We did not  hash check iso file. But Windows  deploys very well but only the update won't launch, it immediately gives a error code in the TS. could it be the ZTIWindowsUpdate script?

Comment: Do you have the WSUS settings in a GPO? You could use `LGPO` to apply them locally. I would personally apply the GPO then run windows update. Tell me if that works.

Comment: We already have a GPO running for WSUS.(It works BTW). 
is it not possible to update during the image process? So that the latest and greatest updates can be installed within the image.

Comment: That is what LGPO does, it sets the settings during the imagining process. Then after LGPO does it's dirty work, you can run the update step. I personally haven't tried this so I am Keen on hearing the results.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this problem before, i remember fixing it by doing some things to the registery.
Although it might not work, maybe you can try something with powershell? 
Also check if the WUASERV are running so it can actually reach the server.

Also make sure that WSUS has full network acces, otherwise it cant connect to the workstation.

Best of luck!